# Sum does not count certain character vectors with summarise in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

When I use sum in base R for a character vector is counts as expected:

```
Letters <- c("A","A","B", "B") 

Pass <- c("Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail")

df <- data.frame( Letters, Pass)

sum(df$Pass=="Fail")
```

---

```
[1] 2
```

When I use sum in dplyr it does not count in the same way:

```
Pass_summary <- df %>% group_by(Letters) %>% 
  summarise(n=n(), 
            Pass=sum(Pass=="Pass"), 
            Fail=sum(Pass=="Fail")
  )
```

[image]

I understand now from MrGrumble's comment that Pass is being reassigned in the 3rd line. Although I thought it was necessary to use mutate() to reference variable that are assigned in the summarise() phase?

Comment: you count within each group. Try to rerun your code without the %>% group_by(Letters)

Comment: In the `dplyr` approach you are grouping `df` by `Letters`. So naturally you are getting `Pass` and `Fail` counts for each letter

Comment: it also does not count fails when I remove %>% group_by(Letters)

Comment: When you get to the 3rd line i `summarise`, with `Fail`, the variable `Pass` has changed. You are literally trying to summarise `sum(Pass=="Pass")`. Try switching the 2nd and 3rd line in summarise.

Comment: Try `table(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `Pass`!

Try switching the order of `summarize`:

```
df %>% group_by(Letters) %>% 
  summarise(n=n(),  
            Fail=sum(Pass=="Fail"),
            Pass=sum(Pass=="Pass")
  )
```

Output:

```
  Letters     n  Fail  Pass
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 A           2     1     1
2 B           2     1     1
```

Or just don't name it "Pass"!